# T-SQL Pivoting approach

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a View that has a structure similar to the following:

```
Id     Name    State    ZipCode   #Requests    AmtReq   Price   Month  Year
1      John    IN       46202      203         33       $300     1     2015
1      Jane    IN       46202      200         45       $100     2     2015
...
```

Queries require reports to be generated for given quarters (1st quarter will include the first three months ...) grouped by state
The result should look like this:

```
                                           Ist Quarter                       ...
                            January                    February              ...
State    ZipCode   #Requests    AmtReq   Price   #Requests    AmtReq   Price ...
IN        46202       203         33       45       200         45      100
```

I feel that this can be done using pivoting but I do not have experience with it. I tried with single column pivoting and had some success, but not in this scale.

Another approach would be to create a stored procedure that will generate the data for me and then just fix some formating (e.g., the first two rows) in the client. Any suggestions on how to approach this problem?

I am using SQL Server as a DBMS.

Comment: SQL Server is one of the best tools for storing and retrieving data. Presentation of data is handled with reporting tool such as SSRS , Qlickview. Your requirement is to present data in a specific way, it will be a lot easier to do it in a reporting tool ( I know SSRS and I can tell you it will be only a matter of few clicks, some column and row grouping) but it SQL Server it will be much more difficult and inefficient to do so.

Comment: I do not have that option though :( 
The requirement is to do it through SQL. I do not have even reporting tools available, my results will be displayed in HTML that communicates through jQuery ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you have MS Excel on your machine then you can export the view to Excel and summarize it to a pivot table. From there you can create table and diagrams as you needed.